# Problem referring to the exe path in _wsystem() in Windows XP

Tags: c++, c

I am having problem referring to the file path in Windows XP (SP2). Actually I want to run an exe file from a specified path say "C:\users\rakesh\Documents and settings\myexe.exe" in my program...I am using the function _wsystem("C:\users\rakesh\Documents and settings\myexe.exe") to run the file..
The problem is that it is not recognizing the space, so I went through some articles and I found an solution for that. I tried using the solution below ..it worked great:

```
C:\\users\\rakesh\\Docume~1\\myexe.exe
```

in the above after the first 6 chars I used "~1" to accomplish the rest...but it's not working when exe name is with space like below:

```
C:\\users\\rakesh\\Docume~1\\my exe.exe
```

and also I can't replace them with "~1"(not working for exe name).

How do you execute programs when there are spaces in the path or executable file name?

Comment: Note that the 8.3 name is __NOT__ made by simply substituting `~1` for the last 6 characters. If you don't believe it, create two files named `123456789.exe` and `12345678_.exe` in the same directory. Obviously they can't both have the 8.3 name `123456~1.EXE`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just like on the command line, the spaces need to be inside double quotes:

```
_wsystem ("\"C:/users/rakesh/Documents and settings/myexe.exe\"");
```

Note that forward slashes work just fine for path delimiters.